# How to convert objects to numeric

Tags: python, pandas

I have very inconsistent data in one of DataFrame columns:

```
col1
12.0
13,1
NaN
20.3
abc
"12,5"
200.9
```

I need to standardize these data and find a maximum value among numeric values, which should be less than 100.

This is my code:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.')) if x.isdigit() else x)
num_temps = pd.to_numeric(df[col],errors='coerce')
temps = num_temps[num_temps<10]
print(temps.max())
```

It fails when, for example, `x` is float `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`.

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you, but could you please check my feedback above your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast value to `string` by `str(x)`, but then for test is necessary also replace `.` and `,` to empty value for use `isdigit`:

```
df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: float(str(x).replace(',', '.')) if str(x).replace(',', '').replace('.', '').isdigit() else x)
```

But here is possible cast values to strings and then use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
num_temps = pd.to_numeric(df["col1"].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')
print (df)
    col1
0   12.0
1   13.1
2    NaN
3   20.3
4    NaN
5   12.5
6  200.9

temps = num_temps[num_temps<100]
print(temps.max())
20.3
```

Alternative:

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return float(str(x).replace(',','.'))
    except ValueError:
        return np.nan

num_temps = df["col1"].apply(f)
print (num_temps)

0     12.0
1     13.1
2      NaN
3     20.3
4      NaN
5     12.5
6    200.9
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your first code, but got this error `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas` at this line `num_temps = pd.to_numeric(df[col].str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')`.

Comment: @Tatik - Is necessary cast to strings like `num_temps = pd.to_numeric(df["col1"].astype(str).str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

`df.replace(",", ".", regex=True).replace("[a-zA-Z]+", np.NaN, regex=True).dropna().max()`